# How do I enable gzip compression in bottle with cherrypy

Tags: python, gzip, wsgi, cherrypy, bottle

The [bottle docs](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/recipes.html#gzip-compression-in-bottle) say:

> ... it is the recommendation of the Bottle project that Gzip compression is best handled by the WSGI server Bottle runs on top of. WSGI servers such as cherrypy provide a `GzipFilter` middleware that can be used to accomplish this.

At present, I'm running my bottle server with:

```
app.run(host='...', port=8080, server='cherrypy')
```

How can I tell cherrypy to use gzip compression?

---

I can get hold of the cherrypy server object like this, but I still can't work out how to enable gzip:

```
class CherryPyGzip(ServerAdapter):
  def run(self, handler): 
    from cherrypy import wsgiserver
    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer((self.host, self.port), handler)

    # enable gzip here somehow?

    try:
      server.start()
    finally:
      server.stop()

app.run(host='...', port=8080, server=CherryPyGzip)
```

Comment: Doesn't bottle do the same thing as cherrypy, except with fewer options, such as the gzip thingy? Why use both. As for gzip - I'm using javascript to gzip it prior to sending. Have you tried that?

Comment: @MarcMaxson: I'm using both because the wsgi server provided with bottle is marked as not terribly suitable for the real world (IIRC, it's not threaded), and the documentation recommends cherrypy for gzipping. Can you elaborate on the JavaScript gzipping thing? That doesn't make any sense to me, since I'm not running nodejs and therefore have no server-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

CherryPy has Gzip tool, but it only works with CherryPy native apps. So you need to use 3rd party Gzip WSGI middleware (wsgigzip is used only as an example, I have no idea which middleware works best):

```
import cherrypy
import wsgigzip


application = wsgigzip.GzipMiddleware(bottle.default_app())

cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': "0.0.0.0",
                        'server.socket_port': 8080})
cherrypy.tree.graft(application, "/")
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Or better yet, use [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) for the server, it [can do gzip](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Transformations.html) in addition to many other great features.

Comment: Where does the `host='...', port=8080` move to?

Comment: @Eric Right, that goes to `config.update()`. The keys are `server.socket_host` and `server.socket_port`.

Comment: Server works, but chrome devtools doesn't report any compression :(

Comment: @Eric Apparently CherryPy's tools won't work with arbitrary WSGI app, so you need to use middleware. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark (since I'm unfamiliar with CherryPy): drop this in where you have the "enable gzip here" comment.

```
cherrypy.config.update({'tools.gzip.on': True})
```

(Inspired by [this](http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2012/12/08/setting-up-a-rock-solid-python-development-web-server/).)

Any luck?

Comment: Bummer.  :(  Hope you figure it out.